# Can't Save MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having an issue with my MySQL query/php, I try to update a row in my database that will work usually, but when the string has a `'` in it, for example

> I don`'`t like green eggs and ham.

The `'` in it will cancel the whole response out and not update the row, so if I put something like this without the `'` for example:

> I dont like green eggs and ham.

The string will save to the row. Below is the MySQL query used and where I get the string from.

```
$NewMessage = $_POST['message123'];

mysql_query("UPDATE Account SET `function` = 'Message', `note` = '$NewMessage' WHERE `id` = '$ID' AND `Online` = '1'");
```

If you need anymore source or anything, please let me know, let me know what you think, thanks!

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` better use prepared statement.

Comment: use mysql_real_escape_string before your variable

Comment: **STOP** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statements.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Wow, forgot all about that, thanks it worked 100%, the smallest things slip me sometimes!

Comment: @Jens Will be using that starting in a few days, this is just for testing, thanks!

Comment: @Melternet It makes no sence to test with this sollution and then change to an other which is so much differend

Comment: @Jens I'm working on an old project of mine that was made in my early years, I'm currently tweaking it and testing, then I'm going to upgrade the MySQL to `PDO` or `MySQLI`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`*_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

```
$NewMessage = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["message123"]);
```

But of course, `mysql_*` API is already [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) and I would recommend to you to use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead.

Comment: Will be using `PDO` very soon, this is just for testing, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hey friend you are need to change single ' with '' commas 2 times. then it is insert your value correct in table other generate error.

Real escape string use where we are need value like this doest. if we user value in database like it does't then right one is use '' 2 time single commas no doule commas

Answer (score 0):

Use simply `addslashes()` To read more about it [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

E.g in you code simply use `addslashes()` something like this

```
$NewMessage = addslashes($_POST['message123']);
```

I hope it will work for you.